# Vertical center when using flex

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my text vertically in my divs, but I'm using `display: flex` so I can't use `display: table`.

What's the best way to vertically center the text here, ideally without adding lots of html elements (hoping to keep the 'thing' divs as clean as possible)?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k93z8joq/)

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thing {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.thing { display: flex; align-items: center; }` will solve the problem.

Comment: So it does! But oddly, then it pushes the text to the left horizontally, ignoring the 'text-align'?

Comment: in that case add also `justify-content: center;`. But as you see in my answer, it works fluently when you use flex-direction.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `.thing { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justif-content: center; }` to the CSS. `flex-direction: column;` will make sure that the normal block-level element behavior is maintained. `justify-content: center;` aligns the items at the cenetr of the main-axis (in this case the vertical axis).

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thing {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` on flex containers will force children to vertically and horizontally center. Add these rules to `.thing` and you'll get your desired results.

```css
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.thing {
    background: red;
    color:white;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex; /* create flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* center vertically */
    flex: 1 0 30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thing {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the most common method of centering text with CSS. To center the text inside each box, we make each containing box a flex container. Then set `align-items` to `center` to perform centering on the block axis, and `justify-content` to `center` to perform centering on the inline axis.

Comment: Ok i will change it

Comment: revoked the down-vote after the edit. However you still have a mistake in there. Its not `block-axis` and `inline-axis`. Those terms makes also no sense at all. Its `main-axis` (justify-content)  and `cross-axis` (align.-items). Those axis depend on the flex-direction. The main-axis is always the same direction as the flex-direction.